# execute server side script for file creations

Tags: node.js

Using node.js, I am developing a small web application where want to create a file on server with a button click on browser. I have a small file "file.js" in public folder as below,

```
var fs = require("fs");

console.log("Going to write into existing file");

fs.writeFile('input.txt', 'Simply Easy Learning!',  function(err) {
   if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
   }

   console.log("Data written successfully! checked");
   console.log("Let's read newly written data");
   fs.readFile('input.txt', function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
         return console.error(err);
      }
      console.log("Asynchronous read: " + data.toString());
   });
});
```

It works fine when i execute this as "node file.js" and creates a input.txt. Calling this file in html page where trying to call through ajax call as below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  

<script>
console.log(' firstpage ');
function readTextFile(){
console.log(' in function readTextFile ');
var dataString;
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "file.js",
  data: dataString,
  success: function(err,data){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + data );
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log(errorThrown);
  }
});

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p class="auto-style1"><strong>Welcome to MyPage</strong></p>
<div >
<input class="myButton" type="button" onclick="readTextFile()" value="Submit" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Pressing the button gives me error,

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:1:10)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at jquery.min.js:2
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.min.js:2)
    at text script (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Pc (jquery.min.js:4)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.min.js:4)
```

please help , where i am making mistake and how to fix. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to help you understand what's going wrong:

1) Running "node file.js" is executing your JavaScript file on your server in a node.js environment.

2) When you run your webpage and fetch and execute file.js, your browser is running file.js using its own JavaScript interpreter directly in the browser.

3) node.js has additional features for server side applications, one being the "require" syntax. This allows server side applications to include other JavaScript files rather than loading them in some HTML with a script src tag

4) node.js also provides some modules that are particularly useful for server side applications, such as "fs"

Your file.js looks like it's coded specifically to be run on the server side rather than on a browser client. It uses node.js syntax and even manipulates a file on the file system

You will need to run a node.js server (express.js being one popular choice) that can execute your file.js via some API endpoint. Then change your browser code to call the endpoint instead of trying to fetch and execute file.js directly in the browser